# How to execute else block only once inside the for loop ?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

In the below code snippet if block will display success alert only when myCity == cites then break the loop execution. But before executing if block else block will execute every index (Ex: cites[0],cites[1],cites[2]) and display Failed alert until if block get succeed.

But i wanted to display Failed alert message only once for whole execution, Anybody can help me out ?

```
    var cites = [ "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Cochin", "Mysore" ];
    var myCity = "Mumbai";
    for (i = 0; i < cites.length; i++) {
        if (myCity == cites[i]) {
            alert("Success:" + cites[i]);
            break;
        } else {
            alert("Failed:" + cites[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is `alert(cites.includes(myCity) ? "Success" : "Failed);`

Comment: What do mean by `show failed only once` -- do you want the failed message when you don't match anything?, OR do you want a failed for anything that does not match? (they are different conditions)

Comment: what should be on alert, if failed?

Comment: The way his code is right now, every failed item in array will `alert` that failed item in the `else` block. By *show failed only once* he wants to display one single alert with all the failed items. He also wants to alert failed items even if there was a successful one. It doesn't make much sense to me, but this is what I understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood you wanted to show `failed` even if there was a successful item. So, store failed in another array, then display it later:

```js
    var cites = [ "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Cochin", "Mysore" ];
    var failed = [];
    var myCity = "Mumbai";
    for (var i = 0; i < cites.length; i++) {
        if (myCity == cites[i]) {
            alert("Success: " + cites[i]);
        } else {
            failed.push(cites[i]);
        }
    }
    if (failed.length > 0)
     alert("Failed: " + failed);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `some` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some) :

```js
var cities = [ "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Cochin", "Mysore" ];
var myCity = "Mumbai";
if (cities.some(function(city){
  return city == myCity
})) {
  alert("Success " + myCity);
} else {
  alert("Failed:" + myCity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra variable to store if result has been found.

```js
var cites = ["Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Cochin", "Mysore"];
var myCity = "Mumbai";
var found = false;
for (i = 0; i < cites.length; i++) {
  if (myCity == cites[i]) {
    alert("Success:" + cites[i]);
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
  alert("Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cites = [ "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Cochin", "Mysore" ],
    myCity = "Mumbai",
    success = false;

for (i = 0; i < cites.length; i++) {
    if (myCity == cites[i]) {
        alert("Success:" + cites[i]);
        success = true;

        break;
    }
}
if (!success) {
    alert("Failed:" + cites[i]);
}
```

this code is correct.